# Changing inline order status in dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to have a status field(say an option set - Fulfilled and Out of Stock) for each item in the order product inline editable grid? I tried adding a field "Item Status" to the Order Line entity form and editing the view but it does not work. Using a third party solution is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the out-of-the-box editable grids. Custom editable grids were introduced in Dynamics 365, but still you will not be able to use it for this case, because they do not support Order Products. You would have to create a custom Order Products if you want to use it, but I believe that's not what you are after. So third-party solution is the only option.

Comment: order product entity is not supported for editable grid in Dynamics 365 (afaik can be enabled only on tablet/phone but not for web) still need to use the "old" inline grid

Comment: yes you are right, I did not see the disabled radiobutton, was mislead by tablet and mobile option. I modified my answer not not mislead anybody else :) thanks @GuidoPreite